# javascript load external file and continue processing

Tags: javascript, callback

So I'm trying to avoid loading certain scripts until the user needs them but I keep ending up in the pattern of using an if...else and putting the call to the continue code in both places. In the code below you can see the two calls to the continueProcessing() method. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
if (typeof sessionList === "undefined" || typeof sessionList != "function") {
  $.getScript('resources/sessionList.js', function() {
    continueProcessing();
  });
} else {
  continueProcessing();
}


function continueProcessing() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Better way means less code & call the continueProcessing() once instead of twice ?

Comment: I dunno. That just doesn't look right to me but the only other thing I can think of is using a timer in a loop and that seems worse. I definitely don't want to over-complicate this and that's about as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used getScript, but have faced a similar challenge with loading html templates. I've  been using the deferred / promise approach. It would look like this for your case:

```
var jqXHR = {};
if (typeof sessionList === "undefined" || typeof sessionList != "function") {
    jqXHR = $.getScript('resources/sessionList.js');
}
$.when(jqXHR).then(continueProcessing());
```

In the case where the script already exists, the jqXHR var will not be a deferred, so the "then" is executed immediately.

This is still a bit of code to type, but at least "continueProcessing" only appears once.

Comment: No need to use `$.when` if you just have a single jqXHR as jqXHR objects already implement the promise interface. And initializing `jqXHR` as an object isn't necessary either - better use `null`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Templates are another area where I load and cache as needed so it definitely applies. I've seen jqXHR but I've never paid attention to it. A quick Google suggests that Deferred is replacing jqXHR. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good way of doing it to me.

Answer (score 0):

So I played with the $.Deferred pattern/code and I came up with this. It's not as terse but I think it's a cleaner way of doing it. Looks like I have a lot of code to refactor...

```
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    if ( typeof sessionList === "undefined" || typeof sessionList != "function" ) {
        $.getScript('resources/sessionList.js', function(){
            dfd.resolve();
        });
    }

    dfd.done(function() {
       continueProcessing();
    });
```

Comment: and I'm an idiot. If the if...then doesn't fire then the deferred statement isn't hit. I know it's bad but a try...catch...finally would do exactly what I want here.